# Is there a way to filter outliers from plots and therefore in the crosstable, I should not see the outliers

Tags: .net, ironpython, spotfire

Is there a way to filter outliers from plots and therefore in the crosstable, I should not see the outliers as well. The outliers are completely zapped from my crosstable.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of outlier?

Comment: case 
    when [Value]>UAV([Value]) then "1"
    when [Value]<LAV([Value]) then "1"
    when [Value]<=UAV([Value]) AND [Value]>=LAV([Value]) then "0"
    end
//
Any values greater than Upper Adjacent Value (UAV) and lower than Lower Adjacent Value (LAV). I create a calculated column in my raw data with the case statement code posted above.

Comment: Is it acceptable to open up the filters and uncheck the "1" option for this column?

Comment: Yes! I'll do that, thank you for your help!